# arrow positioning move upward when zoom in using leafletjs

Tags: leaflet

Anyone knows how to position it correctly even if zoom in? Thanks

```
<div id="image-map"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/zachdunn/pen/VvRXdP

Comment: Leaflet doesn't know which point on your custom marker to place on the marker coordinates. This post on gis explains...https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222971/how-can-i-prevent-leaflet-from-moving-my-marker-while-zooming-into-the-map

Comment: got it. I tried change the iconAnchor but it still not so accurate. Anyway that helps a lot. Thank you.